# Best approach at designing an iOS frontend

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xib

I am designing my first iOS app at the moment. Every view of the app needs to be available in portrait aswell landscape. Also all iPhone versions need to be supporrted.

As someone always working with windows and never owning any apple product it was a pain in the ass getting started but slowly things seem to work out. But before the whole design approach takes a wrong direction I rather ask here:

1. What I want to do is have constraints based on multipliers as much
   as possible.
2. I will try to avoid constant values as much as possible since from
   my understanding they arent scaling. I read that you can change them
   programmatically but if possible I want to stay in the designer for
   frontend related stuff.
3. Since the multiplier cant be changed based on the current size class
   I plan to have a set of constraints for all kind of portrait size
   classes and another one for landscape (using installed feature of
   xcode)
4. To up and downscale labels and textviews I want to have a height
   constraint to the superview with a very tiny multiplier (will
   probably be complicated to keep all textviews the same height when
   there are different parents across them?)

In theory this should produce views which up and downscale well and look the same on all kind of iPhone screens. Now I am curious what more experienced iOS designers think about my "plan":

1. Do you have different approaches?
2. Is there any book/tutorial/page you can suggest?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Pretty broad question, but you are definitely on the right track. Unfortunately with learning Interface Builder and handling constraints, the best tutorial is practice and experience. It's a great tool, but there is a learning curve. Scaling fonts to match design within labels and text views is always a pain. Not the most helpful comment, but your approach is correct - try it!

Comment: It might help to give an example of how you want these views to adapt to different devices. I find that I rarely need multipliers and constants are fine because spacing between views often does not need to scale proportionally with screen size.